# SOQL Query on Collaboration Group fails only in live code, not in Execute Anonymous Window or Query Tab of Developer Console

Tags: apex, soql, batch

Simple SOQL Query fails to yield results in live Apex code, but succeeds in Developer Console Execute Anonymous Window and in Query Editor Tab.

```
public void importProgramCollaborationGroupTable(){
   List<CollaborationGroup> allCollabGroups = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CollaborationGroup];
}
```

Not sure if this will make a difference, but this was in a Batchable, Stateful Class.

Also, this is NOT in a test method.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your class is declared with the keyword `with sharing`

When an apex class has with sharing, note that sharing is enforced and this could be the reason why your queries are returning no results while the same queries show results when ran from executing anonymous.

If you want your class to run in system mode then you can use `without sharing`. Note using `without sharing` is not recommended until you need because of business requirement.

I would research the permissions to see if the user has appropriate permissions before changing to without sharing.

Comment: The batch is being created in an event trigger, so the user id is `autoproc@00d19000000fd64eag`. The class has been run as both `with sharing` and `without sharing` with the same behavior.

Comment: HI Mohith, forgot to say 'thank you' for responding. :)